# How can I get the value of the result in NEO4J Cypher Query in JAVA

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

i'm newbie in neo4j

actually, I write some query to find the distinct cluster number of graph in java

like this

```
result = engine.execute("START n=node:nodes(\"id:"+queryId+"\") "+
"MATCH (n)-[s]-(ns) "+  "WITH collect(distinct ns.cluster) as nc1 "+"RETURN nc1 ");
```

and then I printed the value of nc1 like this

```
for( Map<String, Object> row : result ) {
    for ( Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet() ){

    String key = column.getKey();

    Object value = column.getValue();
    if(key.equals("nc1")){
         System.out.println(value)
    }
}
```

it was successful
I can see the list 
for example, [ 12, 34, 55, 60 ].

but I cannot extract the number of the list

how can I extract the exact value in object value.. I have no idea.

please help me

thank you

Comment: You want to print the key or the values associated with each key?? @kujungmul

Comment: Hmm, I can print the value of nc1, but I don't know how can I extract each element in nc1.

Comment: you can try the codes and check whether it is giving desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your codes to::

```
   for( Map<String, Object> row : result ) {
for ( Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet() ){

String key = column.getKey();

Object value = column.getValue();
if(key.equals("nc1")){
     System.out.println(value);

  int[] array=new int[(int) value];
     System.out.println(array[0]);
     System.out.println(array[1]);
     System.out.println(array[2]);//Upto the no. of value of nc1
}
}
```

Comment: @kujungmul welcome to stackoverflow ,if the answer helped you to solve your problem ,than try voting up or accept the answer,it will help others.